# Android Studio "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String" Crash error

Tags: java, android

I'm new with coding and found a tutorial on YouTube. Badly it doesn't work the way it should. The app keep crashing with this message in the debug console :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.proprietaire.lovechatting, PID: 30321
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.proprietaire.lovechatting.Friends
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source:278)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:22)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:141)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.CachingObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(CachingObservableSnapshotArray.java:40)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:127)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:164)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19758)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19758)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1769)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19758)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19758)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19758)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19758)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19758)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19758)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Here is my code from friend :

```
public class Friends
{
    public String date;

    public Friends()
    {

    }

    public Friends(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And here is the friend fragment :

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment
{
private RecyclerView myFriendsList;

private DatabaseReference FriendsReference;
private DatabaseReference UsersReference;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

String online_user_id;
private View myMainView;


public FriendsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    myMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

    myFriendsList = (RecyclerView) myMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    online_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    FriendsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(online_user_id);
    FriendsReference.keepSynced(true);
    UsersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    UsersReference.keepSynced(true);

    myFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return myMainView;
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>
            (
                    Friends.class,
                    R.layout.all_users_display_layout,
                    FriendsViewHolder.class,
                    FriendsReference
            )
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FriendsViewHolder viewHolder, Friends model, int position)
        {
            viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());

            String list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

            UsersReference.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    String userName = dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue().toString();
                    String thumbImage = dataSnapshot.child("user_thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                    FriendsViewHolder.setUserName(userName);
                    FriendsViewHolder.setThumbImage(thumbImage, getContext());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });
        }
    };

    myFriendsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}


public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    static View mView;

    public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }


    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        TextView sinceFriendsDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_status);
        sinceFriendsDate.setText(date);
    }

    public static void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        TextView userNameDisplay = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_username);
        userNameDisplay.setText(userName);
    }

    public static void setThumbImage(final String thumbImage, final Context ctx)
    {
        final CircleImageView thumb_image = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_image);


        Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumbImage).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile)
                .into(thumb_image, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError()
                    {
                        Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumbImage).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile)
                                .into(thumb_image);
                    }
                });
    }
}
}
```

If anyone has any idea please tell me. Like I said, when someone send a friend request, then the other open the app and when he goes on any fragment unless the settings and the Users list, it crashes. What I was trying to code (copy) was to have a friend fragment where it shows your friends when the friend request was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick

```
String userName = dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue(String.class); 
String thumbImage = dataSnapshot.child("user_thumb_image").getValue(String.class);
```

Here, [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) says method getValue() returns the data contained in this snapshot as native types. You are trying to convert an Object to String instead of that invalid typecasting use another **[getValue(Class valueType)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue(java.lang.Class<T>))** method from the same class which will return value in String dataType if String.class is passed as a parameter

Comment: Please explain how and why it will "do the trick".  The OP probably wants understanding, not "magic".